# slicing a list into a smaller list

Tags: list, recursion, prolog, sublist

I'm currently working through the 99 Prolog problems list [http://www.ic.unicamp.br/~meidanis/courses/mc336/2009s2/prolog/problemas/](http://www.ic.unicamp.br/%7Emeidanis/courses/mc336/2009s2/prolog/problemas/) and am on question 18. It states:

> Given two indices, `I` and `K`, the slice is the list containing the elements between the `I`'th and `K`'th element of the original list (both limits included). Start counting the elements with `1`.
>
> Example query: `?- slice([a,b,c,d,e,f,g,h,i,k],3,7,L).`
> Expected result:  `L = [c,d,e,f,g]`

I've looked at the given solution, but my question was whether anyone could figure out why my solution was wrong? This is my code:

```
chop([H|_],_,End,End,[H]).
chop([_|L],Start,End,Count,Out) :-
    (Count < Start),
    N is Count + 1,
    chop(L,Start,End,N,Out).
chop([H|L],Start,End,Count,[H|Out]) :-
    (Count >= Start; Count < End),
    N is Count + 1,
    chop(L,Start,End,N,Out).

slice(L,Start,End,Out) :-
    (Start =< End),
    Count is 1,
    chop(L,Start,End,Count,Out).
```

My train of thought was: if the element at iteration 'Count' is between the two given limits then add to the list, if not then move on. As an example output, for the call:

```
?- slice([a,b,c,d,e],2,3,X).
```

I get the output:

```
X = [b,c] ? ;
X = [b,c] ? ;
X = [a,b,c] ? ;
X = [a,b,c] ? ;
```

And for the call:

```
?- slice([a,b,c,d,e],3,3,X).
X = [c] ? ;
X = [b,c] ? ;
X = [a,c] ? ;
X = [a,b,c] ? ;
```

The first given list is correct but then it all goes wrong; I've tried using trace but it's boggling my mind.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

the problem you have is that your rules are not mutually exclusive
everything that matches with your second rule

```
chop([_|L],Start,End,Count,Out) :-
```

will also match with your third rule

```
chop([H|L],Start,End,Count,[H|Out]) :-
```

Meaning that once you have found a working answer, and try to find more, every successful branching into the second rule will result in a second answer following the third branch. (hence the additional prepended letter)

you could solve this by adding a cut in at the end of the second rule

```
chop([_|L],Start,End,Count,Out) :-
  (Count < Start),
  N is Count + 1,
  chop(L,Start,End,N,Out),
  !.
```

Comment: Ah fantastic, thank you! Once you pointed out that they weren't mutually exclusive I realised that it should have been:
(Count >= Start, Count < End)
as opposed to:
(Count >= Start; Count < End).
Cheers!

Comment: Can you explain why it is bad advice? I know that this is a red cut, rather then a green cut. But i'm not sure why it is bad practice.

Answer (score 2):

We define `slice/4` based on `append/3` and `length/2`, as defined by the [Prolog Prologue](https://www.complang.tuwien.ac.at/ulrich/iso-prolog/prologue):

```
slice(AsBsCs,P,Q,Bs) :-
   append(AsBs,_Cs,AsBsCs),
   append(As  , Bs,AsBs  ),
   length([_|As],P),
   length( AsBs ,Q).
```

Sample query as given by the OP:

```
?- slice([a,b,c,d,e,f,g,h,i,k],3,7,Xs).
Xs = [c,d,e,f,g] ;
false.
```

Let's generalize above query like this:

```
?- slice([a,b,c,d,e,f,g,h,i,k],P,7,Xs).
  P = 1, Xs = [a,b,c,d,e,f,g]
; P = 2, Xs =   [b,c,d,e,f,g]
; P = 3, Xs =     [c,d,e,f,g]
; P = 4, Xs =       [d,e,f,g]
; P = 5, Xs =         [e,f,g]
; P = 6, Xs =           [f,g]
; P = 7, Xs =             [g]
; P = 8, Xs =              [] 
; false.
```

How about generalizing a different way?

```
?- slice([a,b,c,d,e,f,g,h,i,k],3,Q,Xs).
; Q =  2, Xs = []
; Q =  3, Xs = [c]
; Q =  4, Xs = [c,d]
; Q =  5, Xs = [c,d,e]
; Q =  6, Xs = [c,d,e,f]
; Q =  7, Xs = [c,d,e,f,g]
; Q =  8, Xs = [c,d,e,f,g,h]
; Q =  9, Xs = [c,d,e,f,g,h,i]
; Q = 10, Xs = [c,d,e,f,g,h,i,k]
; false.
```

Last, we run a query which is a generalization of both:

```
?- slice([a,b,c,d,e,f,g,h,i,k],P,Q,Xs).
  P =  1, Q =  0, Xs = []
; P =  1, Q =  1, Xs = [a]
; P =  2, Q =  1, Xs = []
; P =  1, Q =  2, Xs = [a,b]
; P =  2, Q =  2, Xs = [b]
; P =  3, Q =  2, Xs = []
; P =  1, Q =  3, Xs = [a,b,c]
; P =  2, Q =  3, Xs = [b,c]
; P =  3, Q =  3, Xs = [c]
; P =  4, Q =  3, Xs = []
; P =  1, Q =  4, Xs = [a,b,c,d]
; P =  2, Q =  4, Xs = [b,c,d]
; P =  3, Q =  4, Xs = [c,d]
; P =  4, Q =  4, Xs = [d]
; P =  5, Q =  4, Xs = []
; P =  1, Q =  5, Xs = [a,b,c,d,e]
; P =  2, Q =  5, Xs = [b,c,d,e]
; P =  3, Q =  5, Xs = [c,d,e]
; P =  4, Q =  5, Xs = [d,e]
; P =  5, Q =  5, Xs = [e]
; P =  6, Q =  5, Xs = []
; P =  1, Q =  6, Xs = [a,b,c,d,e,f]
; P =  2, Q =  6, Xs = [b,c,d,e,f]
; P =  3, Q =  6, Xs = [c,d,e,f]
; P =  4, Q =  6, Xs = [d,e,f]
; P =  5, Q =  6, Xs = [e,f]
; P =  6, Q =  6, Xs = [f]
; P =  7, Q =  6, Xs = []
; P =  1, Q =  7, Xs = [a,b,c,d,e,f,g]
; P =  2, Q =  7, Xs = [b,c,d,e,f,g]
; P =  3, Q =  7, Xs = [c,d,e,f,g]
; P =  4, Q =  7, Xs = [d,e,f,g]
; P =  5, Q =  7, Xs = [e,f,g]
; P =  6, Q =  7, Xs = [f,g]
; P =  7, Q =  7, Xs = [g]
; P =  8, Q =  7, Xs = []
; P =  1, Q =  8, Xs = [a,b,c,d,e,f,g,h]
; P =  2, Q =  8, Xs = [b,c,d,e,f,g,h]
; P =  3, Q =  8, Xs = [c,d,e,f,g,h]
; P =  4, Q =  8, Xs = [d,e,f,g,h]
; P =  5, Q =  8, Xs = [e,f,g,h]
; P =  6, Q =  8, Xs = [f,g,h]
; P =  7, Q =  8, Xs = [g,h]
; P =  8, Q =  8, Xs = [h]
; P =  9, Q =  8, Xs = []
; P =  1, Q =  9, Xs = [a,b,c,d,e,f,g,h,i]
; P =  2, Q =  9, Xs = [b,c,d,e,f,g,h,i]
; P =  3, Q =  9, Xs = [c,d,e,f,g,h,i]
; P =  4, Q =  9, Xs = [d,e,f,g,h,i]
; P =  5, Q =  9, Xs = [e,f,g,h,i]
; P =  6, Q =  9, Xs = [f,g,h,i]
; P =  7, Q =  9, Xs = [g,h,i]
; P =  8, Q =  9, Xs = [h,i]
; P =  9, Q =  9, Xs = [i]
; P = 10, Q =  9, Xs = []
; P =  1, Q = 10, Xs = [a,b,c,d,e,f,g,h,i,k]
; P =  2, Q = 10, Xs = [b,c,d,e,f,g,h,i,k]
; P =  3, Q = 10, Xs = [c,d,e,f,g,h,i,k]
; P =  4, Q = 10, Xs = [d,e,f,g,h,i,k]
; P =  5, Q = 10, Xs = [e,f,g,h,i,k]
; P =  6, Q = 10, Xs = [f,g,h,i,k]
; P =  7, Q = 10, Xs = [g,h,i,k]
; P =  8, Q = 10, Xs = [h,i,k]
; P =  9, Q = 10, Xs = [i,k]
; P = 10, Q = 10, Xs = [k]
; P = 11, Q = 10, Xs = []
; false.
```